# WPF DataGridCheckBoxColumn's state doesn't get updated from the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a DataGrid (ItemsSource is an ObservableCollection) with a DataGridCheckBoxColumn defined as such:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
          SelectionUnit="FullRow"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserResizeColumns="False"
          CanUserResizeRows="False"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResult, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
<!--additional columns-->
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Add"
                        IsReadOnly="False"
                        Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</DataGrid>
```

Bindings work fine in one direction, the ViewModel can see the changes in the collection but it doesn't work in the other direction. I can of course reinitialize the collection after updating it but that messes up the sorting order, of course.

```
List<int> Ids = new List<int>();
foreach (var result in SearchResult) // binding source, of type ObservableCollection
{
    if (result.IsSelected)
    {
        Ids.Add(result.Id);
        result.IsSelected = false; // should uncheck the corresponding DataGridCheckBoxColumn cell
    }
}
//SearchResult = new ObservableCollection<SearchSeries>(SearchResult); // does the job but rearranges the sorting
//RaisePropertyChanged("SearchResult"); // doesn't work either
```

I'm using VS 2013 and the latest available MVVM Light Toolkit.

Comment: Are you raising the property changed event when IsSelected is changed from the ViewModel?

Comment: Shouldn't the RaisePropertyChanged("SearchResult") line do exactly that if I'm not mistaken? IsSelected is a property of SearchResult's members.

Comment: In the set of IsSelected you should have RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected")

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: I've tried updating other columns to arbitrary values, it works fine. I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to call RaisePropertyChanged() in the IsSelected's setter as @Glen Thomas suggested. It has been a few days since I've asked the question and didn't work on my project in the meantime.
It was the only member of the ObservableCollection's type that didn't invoke the aforementioned method resulting in the DataGrid's inability to "refresh" itself.
The IsSelected property is actually located in the partial class which extends a class generated when adding a web service reference (Reference.cs file). All of the other properties' setters call RaisePropertyChanged().

```
namespace Example.Client.ExampleService
{
    public partial class Search // the rest of the definition is in Reference.cs
    {
        private bool _isSelected;

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return _isSelected; }
            set
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` should be put into `DataGrid.Columns` like this:

```
<DataGrid >
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Second `SearchSeries` should be implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Hope to help you.